# http.Server doesn't have addListener in node.js? It isn't a event emitter?

Tags: node.js

I am just beginning to play around with node.js and was looking through the documentation.  This code doesn't even run:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
http.Server.addListener('request', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.headers);
});
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1');
```

I am trying to add a listener to the server object for the 'request' event.  Under the documentation 'request' is listed as an event under http.Server.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?  How would you go about adding a seperate listener function for the 'request' event? (that is, not overwriting the one added during createServer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `listen` isn't chainable, and you're not storing your server object. Try:

```
var http = require('http');
var myServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
});
myServer.listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
myServer.addListener('request', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.headers);
});
```

That seems to work in my testing.

Comment: I came up with something similar while playing around with it more after posting the question.  Mine doesn't post more than one header per refresh of the browser.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, my earlier note at the bottom was due to my sloppy testing. I've already taken it out. It's getting late, I should get some sleep instead of being on SO. ;-)